Unicode-math package affects bullet size in Beamer
Problem Description:
When I use the unicode-math package in Beamer document and compile it with XeLaTeX, the bullet symbols in the itemize lists appear larger than the default size. This inconsistency in the presentation's appearance is undesirable. How to revert?
What I've Tried:
I have attempted to reset the bullet symbol using \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle] but it did not work.
MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item1
    \item Item2
    \item Item3
    \item Item4
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Two images illustrating the issue:
The first and second images show the appearances without/with the \usepackage{unicode-math} line, respectively.



It uses \blacktriangleright from whichever maths font you're using, so the bullet is coming from your maths font.  So if you want it to look different, you'll need to redefine the template or create a new custom template which uses the character you prefer. At least, this is probably better than trying to override the character in maths, too.

In addition to what @cfr just wrote, if you need a smaller right-pointing triangle like U+25B8 instead of the big one you see (U+25B6), you need a different font than latin modern math (the default?), since it does not have it.

There's a bug which means my pictures are screwy at the moment, but this seems to work:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\amsblacktriangleright} {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"49}
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{moddefault}{\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\amsblacktriangleright$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item1
    \item Item2
    \item Item3
    \item Item4
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[moddefault]{}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item1
    \item Item2
    \item Item3
    \item Item4
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Obviously, you wouldn't switch template mid-document - that's just for demonstration purposes. [At least, I hope it is.]
